# An application using EJB 3.0 and Hibernate persistence provider gives an UnknownServiceException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0, jpa-2.0

I am trying to create a web app using JSF and EJB 3.0.

I am using plain JSF, Glassfish Server, Hibernate as my persistance provider. My database is apache derby.

Here my Stateless Session bean as follows:

```
  @Stateless
  @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
  public class StudentServiceBean implements StudentService{


    @PersistenceContext(unitName="forPractise")
    private EntityManager entityMgr;

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    @Override
    public List<StudentVO> fetchStudentListOrderByStudentId(boolean flag){
        List<StudentEntity> studentList = null;
        TypedQuery<StudentEntity> studentQuery = null; 
        List<StudentVO> studentVOList = null;
        String queryDesc = "select s from StudentEntity s order by s.studentId desc";
        String query = "select s from StudentEntity s order by s.studentId";
        try{

            if(!flag){
                studentQuery = entityMgr.createQuery(query,StudentEntity.class);
            }else{
                studentQuery = entityMgr.createQuery(queryDesc,StudentEntity.class);
            }           

            studentList = studentQuery.getResultList();
            studentVOList = new ArrayList<StudentVO>();
            for(StudentEntity studentE : studentList){              
                studentVOList.add(new StudentVO(String.valueOf(studentE.getStudentId()),studentE.getStudentName(),studentE.getContactNumber()));
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(" EXCEPTION IN "+this.getClass().getName()+" in method fetchStudentListOrderByStudentId "+e);
        }
        return studentVOList;
    }
```

And this is my persistence.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
              version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="forPractise" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/app</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.entity.StudentEntity</class>
        <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.dialect"  value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"  />
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />               
                <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup" />             
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```

What happens is on load of the JSP page, the getter method of StudentList is called -
inside the getter method I have written logic that if `studentList` is empty then call the `studentService.fetchStudentListOrderByStudentId(true);`.

But when I do this I get an exception:

> EXCEPTION IN com.bb.StudentServiceBean in method
>   fetchStudentListOrderByStudentId
>   org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service
>   requested
>   [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]

Can you please tell me what I am missing, or where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you linking against Hibernate 4.x libraries?

Comment: Yes there r hibernate 4 jars in the classpath, except one, i have removed jboss-transaction jar from the classpath, as i am using Glassfish,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You indicate that you are using Hibernate 4.x, but the class you mentioned afaik is only valid for JPA 1.0 and Hibernate 3.x. Try removing the following line from your configuration:

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked.
One more thing, have u read the whole documentation of Hibernate 4 ?
I mean how come you know even the probable property values, like which  property be included and which shouldn't be ?

Comment: Glad it worked. I use Hibernate 4 in a project I am working on now, so I'm getting pretty familiar with it.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it's of any interest, I got this error on Jetty when trying to start a Hibernate session:

Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]

The root cause was a previous Exception (a few seconds earlier in the logs) which caused the spring context (WebAppContext) to fail to initialize.

Once I fixed the spring context, the "Unknown service requested" fixed itself. So, if you're seeing this error it's worth checking for earlier errors before investigating too much..

Comment: It seems it happens against several problems about getting a working EntityManagerFactory instance. For example, I've just debugged a case where the EMF were closed (ie, EntityManagerFactory.close()) by a command-line program being invoked by multiple JUnit methods, the second call to it crashed with this message, cause the EMF was closed.